# Payload becomes undefined when it reaches the worker

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, httprequest, adonis.js, google-cloud-tasks

So, I'm trying to send a task to a google cloud task queue, but when it reaches there, it becomes undefined. Here are the snapshots of my code. What am I doing wrong?

I'm doing it using node.js and the framework Adonis.js. The payload consists on a object with user information. Something like: { first_name: 'Bla', last_name: 'Bla bla', email: 'bla@bla.com'} and so on. I've done tasks who really works before, but I can't find the error in that one... So, here comes my code snippets:

This is where I create the task:

```
const payload = { users }
    const http = {
      method: 'PUT',
      endpoint: '/api/task/users',
      headers: {
        Authorization: request.header('Authorization')
      }
    }

    const task = new Task('users', http, payload)

    try {
      await task.createTask()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      return response.status(500).send({ message: 'Users task: Internal Error!' })
    }
```

This is my Task Class (I did it just like the Cloud Tasks documentation btw):

```
constructor (queue, http, payload = undefined, seconds = undefined) {
    const project = Config.get('google.projectId')
    const location = Config.get('google.location')

    this._client = new cloudTasks.CloudTasksClient()
    console.log(project, location, queue)
    this._parent = this._client.queuePath(project, location, queue)
    this._payload = payload
    this._http = http
    this._seconds = seconds
  }

  async createTask() {
    const task = {
      appEngineHttpRequest: {
        httpMethod: this._http.method,
        relativeUri: this._http.endpoint,
        headers: this._http.headers
      },
    }

    if (this._payload !== undefined) {
      task.appEngineHttpRequest.body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(this._payload)).toString('base64')
    }

    if (this._seconds !== undefined) {
      task.scheduleTime = {
        seconds: this._seconds + Date.now() / 1000
      }
    }

    const request = {
      parent: this._parent,
      task: task
    }

    console.log(`Sending task: ${task}`)
    const [ res ] = await this._client.createTask(request)
    console.log(`Created task ${res.name}`)
  }
```

And this is the worker who will receive the task:

```
async users ({ request, response, domain }) {
    const { users } = request.only(['users'])

    for (const user of users) {
      try {
        let u = await User.findOrCreate({ email: user.email }, user)
        if (u.id) {
          u.merge(user)
          await u.save()
        } else {
          await u.test().associate(test)
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return response.status(500).send(`User Task Error: ${e}`)
      }
    }
```

I was expecting the same object I described before reaching the worker, but I just can get a "undefined" value. Can you guys help me? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to parsing of the incoming request body. By default, the `Content-Type` header of the Task request is set to "application/octet-stream" (https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#AppEngineHttpRequest).

Therefore you may need to set a your parser to the appropriate parsing type (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/blob/master/samples/server.js#L27) or manually set the `Content-Type`.